# How to Install and run a XulRunner Application on Mac OS X? 

Tags: firefox, testing, installation, xulrunner

I'm on a Mac OS X Lion, and I have followed this tutorial exactly as it is:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/getting_started_with_xulrunner

When I try to run:

```
 /Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework/xulrunner-bin --install-app /Users/CIRK/Documents/deskapp.zip
```

Gives me nothing as a result in the terminal, and I can't find any file called `deskapp.app`. So I mean nothing happens at all.

I tried to run it without the installation as it is suggested in the tutorial but doesn't worked :

```
/Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework/xulrunner-bin "/Users/CIRK/Documents/dekapp/application.ini"
```

I installed XulRunner from an installer downloaded from here:

http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/7.0b4/runtimes/xulrunner-7.0b4.en-US.mac-pkg.dmg

when I run `/Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework/xulrunner-bin` I get the help instructions but when I run `/Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework/xulrunner-bin -v` I get an error:

`Mozilla XULRunner <Error> - <Error>`

So what should I do?

Comment: I have installed XULRunner version 7 from your link and I don't know how to access. Please tell me how to access or please tell me how to uninstall? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether `--install-app` is really supported. Running directly should work however, make sure to add `--app` command line flag before the path to `application.ini` however:

```
/Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework/xulrunner-bin --app "/Users/CIRK/Documents/dekapp/application.ini"
```

What happened when you tried to run the app directly? "Doesn't work" isn't a great description...

And one final suggestion: the current **stable** XULRunner release is XULRunner 6.0, you should use it.

Comment: I deleted `/Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework` but I get this error: Mozilla xulrunner 6.0 cannot be installed on this disk. A newer version of this software already exists on this disk.

Comment: Doesn't happened anything when I tried to run in directly. no errors no messages, nothing.

Comment: Hey I figured out to install 6.0 and now it works :) thanks very much!

Comment: @CIRK to install an older version check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434292/how-to-completely-uninstall-xulrunner-7-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 3+ includes xulrunner, you can run any app using:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -app YourApp/application.ini
```