# How to completely uninstall XULRunner 7 Mac OS X

Tags: xul, xulrunner

There is a thread here:

[How to Install and run a XulRunner Application on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332736/how-to-install-and-run-a-xulrunner-application-on-mac-os-x)

...in which a user mentions having trouble **uninstalling** XULRunner 7 so he could then install XULRunner 6. Unfortunately he just says he figured it out, but doesn't say how. It appears that I cannot private-message or email that user (CIRK).

So, does anyone know how one removes it, or at least get OS X to allow the install of XULRunner 6?

As a side-note, removing the /Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework directory does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's hilarious that new users can't self-answer for eight hours. I did find the answer, and will come back tomorrow to post it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question a day later...

It appears that the XULRunner 7 installer not only adds files to the /Library/Frameworks folder, but also adds to /private

Specifically, I had to manually delete...

```
/private/var/db/receipts/org.mozilla.xulrunner.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/org.mozilla.xulrunner.plist
```

...along with removing the /Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework folder.

Hopefully that will be helpful to someone else.

**edit:** This is specifically relevant to OSX 10.6.7, reported to work on 10.7.2 as well

Comment: Thanks, stackoverflow! @Tamur this worked for me on 10.7.2. I wanted to uninstall a beta to install the latest "release".

Comment: Excellent, glad it helped maxwell. Just edited my answer to include 10.7.2, thanks for the note.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X 10.5.8 there is nothing under /private/... but there is a folder /Library/Receipts/xulrunner-*.mac.pkg which have to be removed too

Comment: Good point, thanks... I've edited my answer to include OSX version