# How to use XULRunner to run SQLite Manager outside of Firefox in Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: sqlite, firefox, xulrunner, sqlitemanager

I have installed XULRunner 11.0 (xr) from here:

[Downloads - sqlite-manager - Extension for Firefox and other apps to manage any sqlite database - Google Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/downloads/list)

I have followed the steps listed here:

[kiveo - Mac SQLite Manager Standalone App](http://www.kiveo.net/blog/mac-sqlite-manager-standalone-app/)

I have read and tried the suggestions here (though they're for version 6.0):

[stackoverflow: How to Install and run a XulRunner Application on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332736/how-to-install-and-run-a-xulrunner-application-on-mac-os-x)

I am able to get the help listing with this command:

```
/Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework/xulrunner-bin -h
```

I am able to run the app from Firefox using this command (after changing the max version in sqlitemanager-xr-0/application.ini to 11.0 from 11.0a1):

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox --app ~/Downloads/sqlitemanager-xr-0/application.ini
```

Here are the contents of the application.ini file:

```
[App]
Name=sqlite-manager
ID=SQLiteManager@mrinalkant.blogspot.com
Version=0.7.7
BuildID=201111132204
Vendor=lazierthanthou
Copyright=Copyright (c) 2008 - 2011 lazierthanthou

[Gecko]
MinVersion=2.0
MaxVersion=11.0

[XRE]
EnableExtensionManager=1
```

When I run the following command in Terminal, with or without sudo, it just immediately returns to the command prompt. There are no error messages. No application appears under Applications. Nothing seems to happen at all. (And, despite the stackoverflow page above noting that --install-app may not really be supported, it is in the XULRunner help listing - which I guess doesn't necessarily mean it'll work ;)

```
/Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework/xulrunner-bin --install-app Downloads/sqlitemanager-xr-0/ /Applications
```

Following a suggestion below, I checked for an exit code. The line above is returning 2.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

Just like you did with Firefox, this command should run your app:

```
/Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework/xulrunner-bin --app ~/Downloads/sqlitemanager-xr-0/application.ini
```

Also, the `--app` switch is optional within XULRunner.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can make a self-contained application you can run from the Dock.

Use the `xulrunner --install-app` command to create the application and then copy all contents of `XUL.framework/Versions/Current` into the generated application at `/Applications/sqlite-manager.app/Contents/MacOS`.

You can then create a wrapper script that runs the xulrunner within the generated app with the `application.ini` file as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/271678/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-dock-items).

For example, put the following into `sqlite-manager.app/Contents/MacOS/sqlite-manager` and make it executable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

APP_PATH="/Applications/sqlite-manager.app"

"$APP_PATH/Contents/MacOS/xulrunner" --app "$APP_PATH/Contents/Resources/application.ini"
```

Now you have to tell OS X to run `sqlite-manager` instead of `xulrunner`. You can do that by editing `sqlite-manager.app/Contents/info.plist` and setting `CFBundleExecutable` to `sqlite-manager` like this:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>sqlite-manager</string>
```

The only limitation of this approach is that it breaks when you move the application or rename it. I'd love suggestions on how to get rid of the absolute path within the sqlite-manager script.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
firefox -chrome chrome://sqlitemanager/content/sqlitemanager.xul
```

or on OS X

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -chrome chrome://sqlitemanager/content/sqlitemanager.xul
```

(found on http://www.egeek.me/2013/09/07/how-to-run-sqlite-manager-with-a-single-command/)

works fine for me on UBUNTU 12.04 to start sqlite manager without starting firefox first

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score -1):

If the install was successful, I think the app should be available in some usual place for your system (which wasn't mentioned, but I'm guessing OSX :). Have you looked under /Applications?

To see whether the command failed quietly, you could check its return value. Is there a verbose switch?

```
$ cd narnia
bash: cd: narnia: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
$ cd .
$ echo $?
0
$ cd narnia && echo "success"
bash: cd: narnia: No such file or directory
$ cd . && echo "success"
success
```

Comment: Yes, the system is Mac OS X Lion - that is in the question/subject. Yes, I have looked under /Applications - that is in the content of the question. No, there is not a verbose switch. I will, however, check to see if there is a return value.

Comment: According to this link (the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide), an exit code of 2 indicates "Misuse of shell builtins (according to Bash documentation)", such as a "Missing keyword or command". Hmm... I'll play with the commands a bit, I guess. Here's the link: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Comment: @leanne Point is, non-zero means the process failed and so the thing probably wasn't installed. Finding where and why would be the next step, but it doesn't look like this will be very constructive.

Comment: XTL, yes, I know that non-zero means failure. Your suggestion of checking for the exit code was great! I just had hoped that the exit code of 2 would help me find the where and the why - but no such luck. As far as I can tell, I've got the right keywords and command structure; but there's really no current, good documentation on XULRunner's newer versions. At this point, I've uninstalled XULRunner and will just run the sqlite-manager tool from Firefox - or find a different tool.